# Brown Spots on Lotus Leaves

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, leaves

[image]I’m a new Lotus plant mom and I haven’t a clue what I’m doing.

I live in Thailand so it’s hot and humid. Bought the plant last week.

The water evaporated (not entirely!!) but enough to kill 2 buds and a couple of leaves. I’ve refilled it with water and will continue to keep an eye on it.

Today I noticed some of the earlier leaves have little brown spots on them.

What is this caused from? Can it be fixed?
The newer leaves don’t have the spots on them.

[image]

Comment: Not sure of the cause, but given the number of affected .vs. unaffected leaves in your pictures, I'd remove the affected leaves on suspicion that it could be something that is better removed before it can affect more leaves.

Comment: Will do. Just went to the nursery to get fertilizer and to ask about the leaves. Also told me to cut off the leaves, got organic insecticide too. Will fertilize today too. Was worried about cutting off too many leaves in case the plant didn’t get enough food

Comment: Even though I’ve removed the leaves with the spots, the new leaves are getting spots on them too. 

I have been spraying the plant with natural insecticide, but not sure that’s working if the leaves are continuing to get brown spots 